# ffmpegでrtmp配信を行う

Tags: ffmpeg

ffmpegを使ってmp4ファイルをrtmp配信サーバ(nginx+rtmp_moduleで構築)にアップロードしたいと思っています。

使っているffmpegはstatic ffmpegでffmpeg-git-20170629-64bit-staticを使っています。
OSはCentOS7です。

```
/root/ffmpeg-git-20170629-64bit-static/ffmpeg -re -stream_loop -1 -i test.mp4 -f flv "rtmp://<domain name>/live/aaaa"
```

で行なっていますが、アップロードできないようです。特にffmpegではエラーは出ていませんが、rtmpサーバの状況を見てみると一瞬接続(ss -anで確認)しているものの、しばらくすると接続がなくなります。

rtmp配信サーバ(nginx)のログを確認しましたが、特にエラーどころかアクセスログもありません。
このrtmp配信サーバにWirecastなどでrtmp接続・アップロードを行うと接続・配信はできています。

ffmpegでの指示が間違っているのでしょうか？もしくはffmpegに他のライブラリが必要なのでしょうか？

ffmpegの内容も載せておきます。

```
$ /root/ffmpeg-git-20170629-64bit-static/ffmpeg -V
ffmpeg version N-86676-g45dbb40cd1-static http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.1 (Debian 5.4.1-11) 20170519
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-debug --disable-ffplay --disable-indev=sndio --disable-outdev=sndio --cc=gcc-5 --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-gray --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg
  libavutil      55. 67.100 / 55. 67.100
  libavcodec     57.100.102 / 57.100.102
  libavformat    57. 75.100 / 57. 75.100
  libavdevice    57.  7.100 / 57.  7.100
  libavfilter     6. 94.100 /  6. 94.100
  libswscale      4.  7.101 /  4.  7.101
  libswresample   2.  8.100 /  2.  8.100
  libpostproc    54.  6.100 / 54.  6.100
```

解決方法ご存知の方はご教示お願いします。

なお、

```sh
ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -vframes 1 -ar 44100 -f flv output.flv -loglevel verbose -hide_banner
```

の結果は以下の通りです。

```sh
[h264 @ 0x254fe20] Reinit context to 720x480, pix_fmt: yuv420p  
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'test.mp4':  
  Metadata:  
    major_brand     : isom  
    minor_version   : 512  
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41  
    encoder         : Lavf57.55.100  
  Duration: 00:11:46.76, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2141 kb/s  
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High), 1 reference frame (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(left), 720x480 [SAR 32:27 DAR 16:9], 2000 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)  
    Metadata:  
      handler_name    : VideoHandler  
      timecode        : 00:16:00:05  
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 132 kb/s (default)  
    Metadata:  
      handler_name    : SoundHandler  
    Stream #0:2(eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74)  
    Metadata:  
      handler_name    : TimeCodeHandler  
      timecode        : 00:16:00:05  
Stream mapping:  
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> flv1 (flv))  
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> adpcm_swf (native))  
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help  
[h264 @ 0x25ceb00] Reinit context to 720x480, pix_fmt: yuv420p  
[graph_1_in_0_1 @ 0x261bae0] tb:1/48000 samplefmt:fltp samplerate:48000 chlayout:0x3  
[format_out_0_1 @ 0x269bfe0] auto-inserting filter 'auto_resampler_0' between the filter  'Parsed_anull_0' and the filter 'format_out_0_1'  
[auto_resampler_0 @ 0x254e1e0] ch:2 chl:stereo fmt:fltp r:48000Hz -> ch:2 chl:stereo fmt:s16 r:44100Hz
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0x268c0a0] w:720 h:480 pixfmt:yuv420p tb:1/15360 fr:30/1 sar:32/27 sws_param:flags=2  
Output #0, flv, to 'output.flv':  
  Metadata:  
    major_brand     : isom  
    minor_version   : 512  
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41  
    encoder         : Lavf57.73.100  
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: flv1 (flv), 1 reference frame ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), yuv420p(left), 720x480 [SAR 32:27 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 30 fps, 1k tbn, 30 tbc (default)  
    Metadata:  
      handler_name    : VideoHandler  
      timecode        : 00:16:00:05  
      encoder         : Lavc57.99.100 flv  
    Side data:  
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/200000 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1  
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: adpcm_swf ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 352 kb/s (default)  
    Metadata:  
      handler_name    : SoundHandler  
      encoder         : Lavc57.99.100 adpcm_swf  
No more output streams to write to, finishing.  
frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=5.9 Lsize=      46kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=380792.0kbits/s speed=0.0695x
video:46kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.881673%
Input file #0 (test.mp4):  
  Input stream #0:0 (video): 6 packets read (99870 bytes); 2 frames decoded;  
  Input stream #0:1 (audio): 8 packets read (2376 bytes); 7 frames decoded (7168 samples);  
  Input stream #0:2 (data): 1 packets read (4 bytes);  
  Total: 15 packets (102250 bytes) demuxed  
Output file #0 (output.flv):  
  Output stream #0:0 (video): 1 frames encoded; 1 packets muxed (47183 bytes);  
  Output stream #0:1 (audio): 0 frames encoded (0 samples); 0 packets muxed (0 bytes);  
  Total: 1 packets (47183 bytes) muxed
```

Comment: FFmpegの詳細ログは`-loglevel verbose`で出力可能です。

Comment: [h264_qsv @ 0x2683780] Error initializing the MFX video decoder: not initialized (-8)
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Internal bug, should not have happened　このようなエラーが出ております。

Comment: ログ上はハードウェア映像デコーダ(QuickSyncVideo)の初期化でエラーになっており、RTMP出力以前の問題があるようです。質問本文に`ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -vframes 1 -f flv output.flv -loglevel verbose -hide_banner`のコンソール出力を張ってみてください。

Comment: [adpcm_swf @ 0x39cf000] Sample rate must be 11025, 22050 or 44100
Error initializing output stream 0:1 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:1 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height　と出ております。

Comment: -ar 44100をつけて、ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -vframes 1 -ar 44100 -f flv output.flv -loglevel verbose -hide_bannerとすると、うまくいっているように見えますが出力されたoutput.flvファイルの容量が小さいようです。-rw-r--r-- 1 root  root       47599  7月  2 23:53 output.flv

Comment: ファイルサイズが小さいのは`-vframes 1`で1フレームのみ処理するよう指示しているためです。ログを断片的に提示されても何もアドバイスできません。ログ提示が難しいのであれば、これ以上はお手伝いできません。ご自身で判断ください。

Comment: ログ提示が難しいということではありません。 
上記本文に掲載します。